# Fibermesh to Hair Sheets

Tags: mesh, conversion

Is there a tool that would convert fibermesh hair to game-ready usable hair sheets as shown here:

http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/CreatingHairUsingAlpha.html

Currently I have this:

[image]

Or should I simply put this beard into the dustbin because it cannot easily be converted to some game-ready?

Comment: Voting to close on the basis that the question is unclear, however *as far as I can tell* this is also off-topic as it is not about Blender

Comment: Try to ask your question in the post, links should help as opposed to being the actual question for us to figure out what you want.

Comment: The page you link to doesn't 'convert' particle hair to mesh, it uses particle hairs to create the texture that is used on mesh hair.

Comment: Go to modifiers, find the right Particle System one, and press convert. Is that what you want? Just as a side note, something like a beard is quite often just modelled as a solid textured mesh, as it is much quicker in-game to render.